# How to generate 16-bit CRC table from a polynomial

Tags: crc

I try to modify the CRC module of an existing project. 
Currently it uses CRC-16-CCITT. I know from the code that its polynomial is `0x11021` and its `CRC-Table` is:

```
    static const unsigned short crc_table[256] =
    {
    0x0000, 0x1021, 0x2042, 0x3063, 0x4084, 0x50a5, 0x60c6, 0x70e7,
    0x8108, 0x9129, 0xa14a, 0xb16b, 0xc18c, 0xd1ad, 0xe1ce, 0xf1ef,
    0x1231, 0x0210, 0x3273, 0x2252, 0x52b5, 0x4294, 0x72f7, 0x62d6,
    0x9339, 0x8318, 0xb37b, 0xa35a, 0xd3bd, 0xc39c, 0xf3ff, 0xe3de,
    0x2462, 0x3443, 0x0420, 0x1401, 0x64e6, 0x74c7, 0x44a4, 0x5485,
    0xa56a, 0xb54b, 0x8528, 0x9509, 0xe5ee, 0xf5cf, 0xc5ac, 0xd58d,
    0x3653, 0x2672, 0x1611, 0x0630, 0x76d7, 0x66f6, 0x5695, 0x46b4,
    0xb75b, 0xa77a, 0x9719, 0x8738, 0xf7df, 0xe7fe, 0xd79d, 0xc7bc,
    0x48c4, 0x58e5, 0x6886, 0x78a7, 0x0840, 0x1861, 0x2802, 0x3823,
    0xc9cc, 0xd9ed, 0xe98e, 0xf9af, 0x8948, 0x9969, 0xa90a, 0xb92b,
    0x5af5, 0x4ad4, 0x7ab7, 0x6a96, 0x1a71, 0x0a50, 0x3a33, 0x2a12,
    0xdbfd, 0xcbdc, 0xfbbf, 0xeb9e, 0x9b79, 0x8b58, 0xbb3b, 0xab1a,
    0x6ca6, 0x7c87, 0x4ce4, 0x5cc5, 0x2c22, 0x3c03, 0x0c60, 0x1c41,
    0xedae, 0xfd8f, 0xcdec, 0xddcd, 0xad2a, 0xbd0b, 0x8d68, 0x9d49,
    0x7e97, 0x6eb6, 0x5ed5, 0x4ef4, 0x3e13, 0x2e32, 0x1e51, 0x0e70,
    0xff9f, 0xefbe, 0xdfdd, 0xcffc, 0xbf1b, 0xaf3a, 0x9f59, 0x8f78,
    0x9188, 0x81a9, 0xb1ca, 0xa1eb, 0xd10c, 0xc12d, 0xf14e, 0xe16f,
    0x1080, 0x00a1, 0x30c2, 0x20e3, 0x5004, 0x4025, 0x7046, 0x6067,
    0x83b9, 0x9398, 0xa3fb, 0xb3da, 0xc33d, 0xd31c, 0xe37f, 0xf35e,
    0x02b1, 0x1290, 0x22f3, 0x32d2, 0x4235, 0x5214, 0x6277, 0x7256,
    0xb5ea, 0xa5cb, 0x95a8, 0x8589, 0xf56e, 0xe54f, 0xd52c, 0xc50d,
    0x34e2, 0x24c3, 0x14a0, 0x0481, 0x7466, 0x6447, 0x5424, 0x4405,
    0xa7db, 0xb7fa, 0x8799, 0x97b8, 0xe75f, 0xf77e, 0xc71d, 0xd73c,
    0x26d3, 0x36f2, 0x0691, 0x16b0, 0x6657, 0x7676, 0x4615, 0x5634,
    0xd94c, 0xc96d, 0xf90e, 0xe92f, 0x99c8, 0x89e9, 0xb98a, 0xa9ab,
    0x5844, 0x4865, 0x7806, 0x6827, 0x18c0, 0x08e1, 0x3882, 0x28a3,
    0xcb7d, 0xdb5c, 0xeb3f, 0xfb1e, 0x8bf9, 0x9bd8, 0xabbb, 0xbb9a,
    0x4a75, 0x5a54, 0x6a37, 0x7a16, 0x0af1, 0x1ad0, 0x2ab3, 0x3a92,
    0xfd2e, 0xed0f, 0xdd6c, 0xcd4d, 0xbdaa, 0xad8b, 0x9de8, 0x8dc9,
    0x7c26, 0x6c07, 0x5c64, 0x4c45, 0x3ca2, 0x2c83, 0x1ce0, 0x0cc1,
    0xef1f, 0xff3e, 0xcf5d, 0xdf7c, 0xaf9b, 0xbfba, 0x8fd9, 0x9ff8,
    0x6e17, 0x7e36, 0x4e55, 0x5e74, 0x2e93, 0x3eb2, 0x0ed1, 0x1ef0
    };
```

My question is how the `CRC-Table` is calculated based on the polynomial?
I would apologize if it is a basic question. CRC is relatively new to me and I couldn`t find any resource which meets my requirement.

Answer (score 3):

The CRC table is simply the CRC of the one-byte messages from 0 to 255.

Answer (score 3):

Use it as example.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

void main()
{
    const uint16_t LengthCRC = 16;
    const uint16_t polynomial = 0x1021;
    const uint16_t mask = (1 << (LengthCRC - 1));
    const int32_t N = 256;
    uint16_t tableCRC[N];

    for (int32_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        uint16_t crc = i << 8;
        for (uint8_t bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++)
        {
            if (crc & mask)
                crc = (crc << 1) ^ polynomial;
            else
                crc <<= 1;
        }
        tableCRC[i] = crc;
    }
}
```

### Update.

For using `tableCRC`:

```cpp
uint16_t UpdateCRC(uint8_t byte, uint16_t prevCRC)
{   
    return tableCRC[((prevCRC >> 8) ^ byte) & 0xff] ^ (prevCRC << 8);
}

uint16_t CalcCRC(uint8_t* bytes, int32_t len, uint16_t initValue)
{
    uint16_t prevCRC = initValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        prevCRC = UpdateCRC(bytes[i], prevCRC);
    }
    return prevCRC;
}
```

for CRC-16/CCITT: `initValue = 0xFFFF`

for CRC-16/AUG-CCITT: `initValue = 0x1D0F`

### Update2.

Several interesting things with CRC-16/CCITT as example

- in polynomial representation `p(x) = x^16 + x^12 + x^5 + x^0`
- in hexadecimal representation `0x11021`

What is "bit" of `p(x)` we can use for feedback?
It's a little bit historical question which has several answers:

1. We can use `x^0` for feedback, then `polynomial = 0x8810`
2. We can use `x^16` for feedback, then `polynomial = 0x1021`
3. We can use `x^0` for feedback with bits reversed, then `polynomial = 0x0811`
4. We can use `x^16` for feedback with bits reversed, then `polynomial = 0x8408`

p.s. `x^0 = 1`